# How to use in memory transport with shared transport provider in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm trying to follow this guide in order to be able to create some functional tests:

https://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/transports/in_memory.html

The thing is that neither `InMemoryTransportCache` class, nor `SetTransportProvider` method can be imported. I also can't find them declared in MassTransit sources on github. How do you achieve what that link up top is describing?

Comment: You're looking at very old documentation, you can find the current documentation for the in-memory transport here: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/in-memory.html. It doesn't mention the transport cache, and it's possible it's been removed. Perhaps you could elaborate on your use-case for the transport cache?

Comment: I'm running 2 asp.net core `TestServer` instances inside a functional test (it's all a single process). I need a producer inside the first server `Send` a command that will be handled by a consumer inside the second one. Currently the breakpoint inside the consumer class is not getting hit. In the debug mode, I can see that both buses have different addresses.

Comment: Also, the consumer is registered correctly and I know that, because when I run the app in a standard way, that breakpoint is getting hit. I also tried adding `Task.Delay(10000)` after I publish the command, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: There is no way to create two bus instances with a shared in-memory fabric. It hasn't been supported for several versions, probably going to back to v3/v4.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, out of curiosity: why did you remove it?

Comment: I'm sure I had a reason. It was years ago.

Comment: Still actual, to be honest. Without this feature configuration of two separated DI containers becomes pain if even possible - too many duplicated code with reregistration of same endpoints dozen of times in every test, instead of using per-module registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - that documentation is outdated, but my questions was still valid. After all, I decided not to go with the suggested approach of setting up a Docker container for the message broker, but instead I used the test harness (also suggested above). I'm using SpecFlow, so the general code is to create and start the harness in the `BeforeScenario` step, like this:

```
[BeforeScenario]
public async Task BeforeScenario() {
    _testHarness = new InMemoryTestHarness();

    await _testHarness.Start();
    TestStartup1.SetHarness(_testHarness);
    TestStartup2.SetHarness(_testHarness);

    // build WebHost and start both asp.net TestServer instances
}

[AfterScenario]
public async Task Cleanup() {
    await _testHarness.Stop();
}
```

And get the `IBusControl` instance from the harness, inside both test startups:

```
// test startup1
public override void UseMassTransit(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMassTransit(_ => {
        // configure endpoints here, etc.

        return _testHarness.BusControl;
    }, RegisterConsumers);
}

// test startup2
public override void UseMassTransit(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMassTransit(_ => {
        // configure endpoints here, etc.

        _testHarness.Bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint("your-endpoint", ep => ep.ConfigureConsumers(serviceProvider));

        return _testHarness.BusControl;
    }, RegisterConsumers);    
}
```

I have yet to see how to make messages handling synchronous, so that I won't have to await the results, but anyway the above code solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the docs you are reading are beyond irrelevant.

Here is how you can test your application with test harnesses: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html

Basically, there's no need to spin up the test server, unless you want to test your registrations. It's quite a heavy job to be done for all your tests.

The docs supply a brief example for testing a consumer, so I just copy-paste it here:

```
public async Task Should_test_the_consumer()
{
    var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
    var consumerHarness = harness.Consumer<MyConsumer>();

    await harness.Start();
    try
    {
        await harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new MyMessage());

        // did the endpoint consume the message
        Assert.IsTrue(harness.Consumed.Select<MyMessage>().Any());

        // did the actual consumer consume the message
        Assert.IsTrue(consumerHarness.Consumed.Select<MyMessage>().Any());
    }
    finally
    {
        await harness.Stop();
    }
}
```

The test project for test harnesses also have a bunch of good examples: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing

Comment: I can't use the test harness. What I'm writing is an integration test using Asp.Net Core test servers: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/testserver.aspx. This means that for each web-app project that my solution consists of, I'm spinning up Asp.Net Core test server, so that I can check the app top to bottom.  I'm checking lots and lots of things in such tests, and one of them is top to bottom message handling. Summing it up: it's not a unit test, but an integration test and that's why I won't use test harness.

Comment: I don't know your topology, but if you have an API controller that sends a message, you just need to call that API using the test client and check the result. There's no need for in-memory transport there, use the same transport that you'd use in production, otherwise you'd never say that your integration tests actually test the integration...

Comment: There's a need for an in-memory transport, because I want my tests to also be fast. I'd like to avoid having to setup the whole RabbitMQ infrastructure (+tear down) for those tests as well. Maybe I made some terminological mistakes using the term "integration test", so I'll try to clear them out. I'm checking the integration of different parts of my system, but I don't see the need to check if I've actually set up the infrastructure correctly. I managed to create such a (maybe "functional" would be a better word?) test framework in one of my past projects and we prooved it's enough for us.

Comment: And I'd like to repeat that here, but I just can't remember how I did it back then...

Comment: I am not sure what's there to set up. All you need to do is to run a RMQ Docker container and then stop it. We do it all the time. It takes like 3 sec to spin up when the image is already downloaded.

Comment: Yep, I'm starting to think I will have to explore that route, though that would inevitably mean that I will have to introduce some delays in my tests for the consumers to catch up. Otherwise the tests will fail randomly due to timing issues. That's the problem I see here, as in the past, I managed to do it all synchronous, all in-memory and everybody loved it, because it meant that running a functional/integration against the system was only a tiny bit slower, than running a unit test.

Comment: Still, I for example, doesn't have ability to run docker. What's then? Considering MassTransit by now have over 14m downloads, now I think that every project which uses it, either promotes code duplication of registrations, or runs a bunch of docker containers.

Comment: @eocron not exactly sure what you mean by promoting code duplication. If you develop an application using MassTransit, you should be able to access the broker, one way or another. In-memory transport can support simple scenarios, but you can never be sure the code built for in-memory transport would actually work with the real broker.

Comment: You indeed go with risk of malfunctioning broker when using in-memory. But why it is even here in first place if all can be done just by initializing gigantic environment? In-memory serves concrete purpose - no errors on broker, just for tests of main workflows. And yes, if you work with DI you actually doesn't have access to inner configuration, you just have interfaces which you can rebind, in case of masstransit - there is need to make shared message broker in tests, but it is not supported. So, probably will switch my project to conrete implementation of Kafka/RabbitMQ

Comment: I don't know how your system is built, so I cannot answer any of these questions. I don't understand why is it a problem to register the initialised bus of the harness in the test container. I do know that when using the `TestServer` I am effectively doing the contract-based, outside-in tests, which require a real broker. I also know that the harness alone is perfectly suitable for testing consumers and producers. Lastly, I don't really understand how using the RMQ client will solve the "I cannot run the broker" issue. But let me stop here as it's not the right palce.